# Crie uma procedure que ao informar uma data, ela retorne o dia da semana correspondente a data informada. MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Gente to com o seguinte problema, estou tratando datas no formato "AAAA-MM-DD", alguém tem uma ideia de uma possível solução ?

estou usando SELECT WEEKDAY ('1999-08-06') AS dia_da_semana;

como posso guardar isso em uma variavel, e depois fazer um IF para me rotornar tipo 0 - segunda, 1- terça ....

SELECT WEEKDAY('1999-05-25')
a data é um exemplo
esse select resolveu meu problema, obrigado a todos que tentou ajudar

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer?

Comment: a respeito dessa questão eu não faço a minima ideia, eu to pesquisando métodos do mysql que trata de datas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `DATEPART` para obter o dia da semana:

```
DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2007-04-21 ')
```

---

> [**DATEPART - Argumentos week e weekday de datepart**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#week-and-weekday-datepart-arguments)
>
> Essa função retorna um inteiro que representa o datepart especificado do argumento date especificado.
>
> ...
>
> Quando datepart é week (wk, ww) ou weekday (dw), o valor retornado DATEPART depende do valor definido usando [`SET DATEFIRST`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Obrigado pesquisando sobre ++ eu achei esse SELECT WEEKDAY ('1999-08-06') AS dia_da_semana;